# How to make Eclipse load all properties from Ant properties file?

Tags: eclipse, ant

I am using Eclipse 3.2.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 Beta (Tikanga) and am trying to create a project using an Ant build file and properties file.  When I load the build file the only properties that are loaded are the ${build.dir}, ${bin.dir}, and ${dist.dir}.  All the other properties in the properties file do not load.  Can anyone help me determine why the rest of the properties would not be loading?  Please see the code below.

build.properties:

```
bin.dir=bin
build.dir=build
dist.dir=dist
src.dir=src
doc.dir=doc
config.dir=config
common.lib.dir=lib
reports.dir=reports
```

build.xml:

```
tools.lib.dir=tools/lib
tools.etc.dir=tools/etc
findbugs.home.dir=tools/findbugs
findbugs.lib.dir=tools/findbugs/lib

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="FalconLogParser">
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${common.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="run.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
        <path refid="compile.classpath" />
    </path>

    <path id="dist.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <path refid="compile.classpath" />
    </path>

    <path id="tools.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${tools.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="findbugs.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${findbugs.lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Create directories to place classes and JARs -->
    <target name="init" description="Create directories to place classes and JARs">
        <tstamp />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/3rdparty" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/com" />
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}/3rdparty" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/bin" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/bin/3rdparty" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/cfg" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/config" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/logs" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/output" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}/scripts" />
    </target>

    <!-- Remove all build artifacts -->
    <target name="clean_build" description="Remove all build artifacts">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${bin.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Remove all reports -->
    <target name="clean_reports" description="Remove all reports">
        <delete dir="${reports.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Remove all build artifacts -->
    <target name="clean_docs" description="Remove all documention">
        <delete dir="${doc.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Compile source code -->
    <target name="build" depends="init" description="Compile Java files">
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/3rdparty" >
            <fileset dir="${common.lib.dir}"/>
        </copy>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}">
            <src path="${src.dir}" />
            <include name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
            <!-- So that Eclipse automatically copies changed files to build directory -->
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- Run unit tests -->
    <target name="test" depends="build" description="Run unit tests">
        <junit description="AllTests" fork="yes">
            <batchtest todir=".">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
            <formatter type="xml" usefile="yes" />
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="yes" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="run.classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <!-- Make distribution jar files -->
    <target name="jar" depends="build" description="Make distribution jar files">
        <jar destfile="${bin.dir}/falconLogParser.jar" basedir="${build.dir}/com" />
        <copy todir="${bin.dir}/3rdparty">
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}/3rdparty" />
    </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- Make distribution files -->
    <target name="dist" depends="jar" description="Make distribution files">
        <copy todir="${dist.dir}/bin">
            <fileset dir="${bin.dir}" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${dist.dir}/config">
            <fileset dir="${config.dir}" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- Make Java documentation for API -->
    <target name="doc" depends="build">
        <delete dir="${doc.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}" />
        <javadoc doctitle="Falcon Log Parser" classpathref="run.classpath" destdir="${doc.dir}" private="true">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.java" />
                <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
            </fileset>
            <link href="${java.apidoc.url}" />
        </javadoc>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="build">
    </target>

    <!--  Static code checking -->
    <target name="checkcode" description="Static source code code checking" depends="build">

        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" id="tocheck">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
            <exclude name="**/*Test.java" />
        </fileset>

        <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}" />

        <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="tools.classpath" />
        <pmd rulesetfiles="basic,design,coupling,strings" targetjdk="1.6">
            <formatter type="xml" toFile="${reports.dir}/pmd_report.xml" />
            <fileset refid="tocheck" />
        </pmd>
        <xslt in="${reports.dir}/pmd_report.xml" style="${tools.etc.dir}/wz-pmd-report.xslt" out="${reports.dir}/pmd_report.html" />
        <echo message="${reports.dir}/pmd_report.xml and ${reports.dir}/pmd_report.html written out" />

        <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpathref="tools.classpath" />
        <checkstyle config="${tools.etc.dir}/sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
            <formatter type="xml" tofile="${reports.dir}/checkstyle_report.xml" />
            <fileset refid="tocheck" />
        </checkstyle>
        <echo message="${reports.dir}/checkstyle_report.xml written out" />
        <xslt 
            in="${reports.dir}/checkstyle_report.xml" 
            out="${reports.dir}/checkstyle_report.html" 
            style="${tools.etc.dir}/checkstyle-noframes-sorted.xsl" 
        />

        <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" classpathref="findbugs.classpath" />
        <findbugs home="${findbugs.home.dir}" output="xml" outputFile="${reports.dir}/findbugs_report.xml">
            <auxClasspath refid="compile.classpath" />
            <sourcePath path="${src.dir}" />
            <class location="${build.dir}/com" />
        </findbugs>
        <echo message="${reports.dir}/findbugs_report.xml written out" />
        <xslt 
            in="${reports.dir}/findbugs_report.xml"
            out="${reports.dir}/findbugs_report.html"
            style="${findbugs.home.dir}/src/xsl/default.xsl"
        />

    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer is that that file is not the file you pasted here. The easiest way to find out what is wrong, to paste the following somewhere to see loaded file:

```
<property name="whatswrong" location="build.properties"/>
<echo>The absulute path of property file is ${whatswrong}/>
```

This is based on the fact, that location attribute always will give back absolute path.

ps: use maven, since your build script is just like a lifecycle